# Hoeffdings Bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have seen the proof of Hoeffding's Bound for bounded RV $X_i\in(m_i,M_i)$

$$\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(X_i-\mathbb{E}[X_i])\ge t\bigg\}\le \text{exp}\bigg(\frac{-2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(M_i-m_i)^2}\bigg)$$

and am able to follow it. As an  exercise in  the textbook High  Dimensional Probability: An Introduction with Application to Data Science you are asked to prove the statement but with a different absolute constant different  from 2. I am not able to see how one can improve the bound. How does one go about showing the inequality with a different absolute constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about Exercise 2.2.7 of [Vershynin's book](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf). This is not asking you to *improve* on the constant $2$: it is asking to prove the result for *some* constant $C>0$ (i.e., larger than 2 is OK if you can't get the optimal one).

Indeed, one can see that the constant $2$ is tight, taking $m_i = -1, M_i = 1$ for all $i$ and considering $X_1,\dots, X_n$ i.i.d. Rademacher random variables (symmetric  Bernoulli).

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how the evaluation of symmetric bernoulli  implies  that the constant 2 is quite tight? The only thing I can think of is using relation $X_i=2Y_i-1$ where $Y_i\sim \text{bern}(\frac{1}{2})$follows a symm bernoulli to find $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i=\frac{t+n}{2})$ and then use sterlings approximation to show its is very close to the upper bound from above.

Comment: @NoeVidales consider the symmetric Bernoulli case, normalize the sum by $1/\sqrt n$ (so the $t^2$ in the RHS changes too, and the $n$ cancels in the RHS) and then let $n$ grow in the LHS to use the CLT and compare to the tail for a Gaussian.